# Nested Recycler view is laggy while scrolling for the first time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

Here, I have two recyclerview that has *parentRecyclerViewAdapter* and *childRecyclerViewAdapter*. Parent adapter has **LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL** layout manager whereas Clild adapter has **GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2)** layout manager with itemDecoration.

When scrolling for the first time the RecyclerView scrolling is laggy and once the data is viewed the scrolling is smooth. Until the app instance is not completely removed the scrolling will be smooth and when the app reinitiate the scrolling is laggy again.

Please help me out to figure out this BUG!!

**ParentRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerListItemClick onListClick;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
        onListClick = (RecyclerListItemClick) context;

    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ItemRowHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_template_section, null));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList = dataList.get(i).getTemplateModelArrayList();
        String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);
        TemplateChooserAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new TemplateChooserAdapter(mContext, templateModelArrayList , dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle());

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView itemTitle;
        private RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        private ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.recycler_view_list.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
            this.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2));
            this.recycler_view_list.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(2 , 25 , false));

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        onListClick.onRecyclerItemClicked(dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getHeaderTitle());

        }
    }

}
```

**ChildRecyclerAdapter**

```
public class TemplateChooserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TemplateChooserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = TemplateChooserAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList;
    private OnTemplatesListClicked onListClick;

    public TemplateChooserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList, String sectionName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.templateModelArrayList = templateModelArrayList;
        onListClick = (OnTemplatesListClicked) context;
        AppUtils.showLog(TAG, "CorporateUserAdapter");

    }

    @Override
    public TemplateChooserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_template_chooser, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.templateView.setImageResource(templateModelArrayList.get(position).getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return templateModelArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView templateView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            templateView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.template_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            templateModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setShowIndicator(true);
            onListClick.onTemplateClick(templateModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition())); // TODO send model when item clicked

        }
    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
private void recyclerViewJob() {

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, allSampleData);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**SectionDataModel.java**

```
public class SectionDataModel {


    private String headerTitle;
    private ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList;


    public SectionDataModel() {

    }

    public SectionDataModel(String headerTitle, ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList) {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
        this.templateModelArrayList = templateModelArrayList;
    }


    public String getHeaderTitle() {
        return headerTitle;
    }

    public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
    }

    public ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> getTemplateModelArrayList() {
        return templateModelArrayList;
    }

    public void setTemplateModelArrayList(ArrayList<SingleTemplateModel> templateModelArrayList) {
        this.templateModelArrayList = templateModelArrayList;
    }

}
```

**SingleTemplateModel.java**

```
public class SingleTemplateModel {

    private String title;
    private String skuName;
    private int image;
    private boolean showIndicator;

    public SingleTemplateModel(String title, String skuName, int image, boolean showIndicator) {
        this.title = title;
        this.skuName = skuName;
        this.image = image;
        this.showIndicator = showIndicator;
    }

    public String getSkuName() {
        return skuName;
    }

    public void setSkuName(String skuName) {
        this.skuName = skuName;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean isShowIndicator() {
        return showIndicator;
    }

    public void setShowIndicator(boolean showIndicator) {
        this.showIndicator = showIndicator;
    }
}
```

**single_row_template_section.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**single_row_template_chooser.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/template_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/model_9" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What exactly is `SingleTemplateModel`? Also please add layout xml for `single_row_template_choose`r and `single_row_template_section`

Comment: @egoldx Model and layouts are mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @jazzbpn ! Did you solve your problem? :)

Comment: @Blunderer Please use Picasso library to load image.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot dude ;) Didn't think about it before :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to lazy load your images from resources. There are libraries like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) that will help you with that.

So it may look like this:

Picasso:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
...

public class TemplateChooserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TemplateChooserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
...

    @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(templateModelArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.templateView);
   }
...

}
```

Comment: I am loading the image resources from drawables/mipmap. The Image file size are around 100-200 kb.

Comment: That doesn't matter, 200kb is actually pretty large, you should definitely load them asynchronously

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to write that by yourself, use that Picasso library, it is much easier

Comment: I am loading the image resources from drawables/mipmap. So why do I use picasso ?

Comment: Loading images from resources is not instant, it just takes a while - load the file, create bitmap, etc. Have you already tried suggested solution?

Comment: I am looking for some optimization things without using third party library.